# How can get access to image and sounds from a npm package that I've published?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, assets

## Background

I have made a simple game to learn how to use Phaser 3 & TypeScript. The game works when I load it locally and run it. I have turned the game into a package hosted on github, you can see it [here](https://github.com/joe-lloyd/phaser-game-flappy-bird/packages/404969?version=1.1.2). My idea was to load the game as a package in an electron app.

So I made an electron app with the TypeScript boilerplate and imported my game.

## Some code

This is how I've brought in my package in electron renderer.ts file

**renderer.ts**

```
import * as Phaser from "phaser";
import config from "@joe-lloyd/flappy-bird-phaser/lib";

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

## Issue

My game loads when I start but crashes out with a load of errors sayign that assets cannot be accesed.

[image]

I feel like I'm missing something fundemental. It looks like my assets path is wrong. It feels strange that the assets are not read relative to the import of the package. Do I need to bundle my assets in a different way or something else?

## Edit 1

I've added a public path to the build process of parcel so it looks like this

```
"build:package": "parcel build index.ts  --public-url ./lib --out-dir lib"
```

and this give me a slightly better result in my electron app. I have part of a path that makes (a little) more sense now.

[image]

As you see I'm still missing this part `\node_modules\@joe-lloyd\flappy-bird-phaser\`

Answer (score 0):

## Add the whole missing path top your public path

I'm not happy with this answer but I will post it incase someone runs into trhis in the future. I would happily accept something more solid.

What I did to correct my assets path inside my electron app was adjust the public path to include the node modules and package name.

The build process now looks like this

```
"build:package": "parcel build index.ts --public-url ./node_modules/@joe-lloyd/flappy-bird-phaser/lib --out-dir lib"
```

Again, I would prefer something more stable but this removed my error.